# How often small GC is triggered in node js?

Tags: node.js

I have been using [appmetrics](https://github.com/RuntimeTools/appmetrics) to monitor GC in node js app. I am seeing small GC event every couple of seconds. Is it normal? Also, I have set the memory to 2 GB but the logs show that only around 80-90 MB of heap is used.

Sample log from app metrics:

```
{"time":1523390469898,"type":"S","size":81068032,"used":44745080,"duration":3}

{"time":1523390678028,"type":"M","size":88408064,"used":35710552,"duration":2}
```

Answer (score 2):

The small / scavenge garbage collector is designed to [run regularly and be very fast](https://v8project.blogspot.ca/2015/08/getting-garbage-collection-for-free.html). It will be under 10ms in nearly all cases, practically often as fast as 1ms, and for your example it appears to be 3ms. It's very fast because it only operates on a small subsection of memory containing newly allocated items since the last scavenge garbage collection.

It also isn't generally related to how much of your maximum heap size you're using, since those events are largely tied to the other garbage collection algorithm (mark and sweep) that manages older, longer lasting references.

This small GC is triggered by a number of things (including some heuristics) that can make it difficult to determine precisely what triggered it, but every couple seconds is nothing to be concerned about in practice since it's only blocking for 1-10ms. Under high load applications it will actually run much more often.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your code and how much garbage is created, but garbage collection calls each couple of seconds is pretty normal as default JS code usually creates objects constantly. If you have a problem with GC, try to reduce object allocations and just modify their properties, when needed.

Also, setting the memory to 2 GB does not mean that it will allocate 2 GB. It means that it will allocate UP to 2 GB when needed, but not more than that.